# Android layout width for text

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I can't set the width of my detail textview correct. It keeps crossing other textviews. It is the detail textview that is overlapping the id and the arrow image. Maybe someone could help me spot the error in my code.

Thanks

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">
<!--  Thumnail -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_product"
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="90dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- Objectnaam-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_row_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
<!-- Detail -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_row_note"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_row_name"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" />
<!-- ID -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt_row_name"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
<!--Arrow -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Well, you didn't tell it to stay away from the other textViews, you only told it to stay at the right of thumbnail. :) There are plenty of options to use: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dip">
<!--  Thumnail -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="3dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img_product"
            android:layout_width="90dip"
            android:layout_height="90dip" />
    </LinearLayout>
<!-- Objectnaam-->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_row_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
        android:textColor="#040404"
        android:typeface="sans"
        android:textSize="15dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
<!-- Detail -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_row_note"
        android:layout_width="150dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/txt_row_name"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/txt_id"
        android:textColor="#343434"
        android:text="sdfsdfsdfsdf"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail" />
<!-- ID -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txt_row_name"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
        android:textSize="10dip"
        android:textColor="#10bcc9"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
<!--Arrow -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/arrow"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

check this code

or just add

```
 android:layout_alignLeft="@id/image"
```

below

```
android:id="@+id/txt_id"
```

and just add

```
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/thumbnail"
```

below

```
 android:id="@+id/txt_row_name"
```

and you may need to re-order or the view definition first image, then id text,then txt_row_name

Comment: Thanks for showing me that I needed a android:layout_toLeftOf="id...". That was my problem!